# Restlet SSL without Keystore

Tags: java, ssl, restlet, restlet-2.3.1

Is it possible for Restlet to use SSL certificates without a keystore? My application currently uses the `DefaultSslContextFactory` like this.

```
    ...
    int httpPort = appConfig.getHttpPort();
    int httpsPort = appConfig.getHttpsPort();

    Component c = new Component();
    c.getDefaultHost().attach(ROOT_PATH, new WebApiApplication());

    if (new KeyStoreManager().defaultJksContainsAlias("tls")) {

        char[] secret = appConfig.getJksSecret().toCharArray();
        String keystore = appConfig.getJksKeystore();

        // Increase the ports until we find a suitable one
        while (occupied(httpsPort)) {
            httpsPort++;
        }
        Server https = new Server(c.getContext().createChildContext(), Protocol.HTTPS, httpsPort, c);
        System.out.println("Starting HTTPS services on port " + httpsPort + "...");

        DefaultSslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new DefaultSslContextFactory();
        sslContextFactory.setProtocol("SSL");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(keystore);
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(secret);
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreKeyPassword(secret);
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreType("JKS");
        https.getContext().getAttributes().put("sslContextFactory", sslContextFactory);
        c.getServers().add(https);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No TLS certificates detected. Skipping HTTPS services...");
    }

    // Increate the ports until we find a suitable one
    while (occupied(httpPort)) {
        httpPort++;
    }
    System.out.println("Starting HTTP services on port " + httpPort + "...");

    Server http = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, httpPort, c);
    c.getServers().add(http);
    try {
        c.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Failed to start core component", e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    ...
```

The problem is that the Java keystore isn't very friendly when it comes to importing existing certificates! Ideally I would like to just specify the path the `.key` and the `.crt` in the same way I do it for **nginx**.

Comment: Have you ever managed to find a solution for this, I'm facing a similar problem?

Comment: No unfortunately I haven't found a direct solution. However, I did solve the problem indirectly by putting the server using plain http behind a load balancer and do https -> http forwarding.